# How does visual studio read instructions from code?

Tags: visual-c++

Hi there StackOverflow community. I’ve faced a certain issue in understanding how visual studio processes the ‘instructions’ given by the code.

the code I’ve written was giving me a problem when i was running it.
It went something like:

whats your guess?
donkey

whats your guess?
donkey

your guess was: donkey

whats your guess?
dog

whats your guess?
dog

your guess was: dog.

It works correctly on alternative tries.
However, if i were to remove ' GetGuess();' on line 38. everything works perfectly fine.
However, it just bothers me that the Getguess on line 38 is nt require because the thought im having right now is that it has to process Getguess first before it processes giving back the guess.

Thank you

code:

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <string>;

using namespace std;
void PrintIntro();
void play_game();
string GetGuess();


// entry point for out application
int main()
{
    PrintIntro();


    play_game();


}

//intro game
void PrintIntro()
{
    constexpr int WORD_LENGTH = 5;
    cout << "welcome to bulls and cows\n";
    cout << "can you guess the " << WORD_LENGTH << " letters word?\n";
    return ;
}


void play_game()
{
    // loop for number of turns asking for guesses
    constexpr int number_of_turn = 5;
    for (int count = 1; count <= number_of_turn; count++)
    {

        GetGuess();
        string guess = GetGuess();
        cout << "your guess was:" << guess << endl;

    }
}


//gut guess from player
string GetGuess()
{
    // ask for a guess
    cout << "whats your guess?\n";
    string guess = "";
    getline(cin, guess);


    return guess;
}
```

Comment: Please paste your code instead of linking to external resource

Comment: Visual Studio processes C++ code according to the C++ standard. It sounds like your code has a bug in it. It would be best to edit the code into your question as a [mcve] and ask specifically about the issue you're having, not a philosophical discussion of how Visual Studio processes code.

Answer (score 0):

A piece of advice: When you run the code please put breakpoints, especially if you want to know how your code run.

"It works correctly on alternative tries. However, if i were to remove ' GetGuess();' on line 38. everything works perfectly fine. However, it just bothers me that the Getguess on line 38 is nt require because the thought im having right now is that it has to process Getguess first before it processes giving back the guess."

To answer your question, first your must know that, when you call "string guess = GetGuess();" the compiler already retrieve the return value and store it into "guess" (in this case, the function return guess), therefore you don't have to add GetGuess() anymore (this is redundant). Your thinking that the compiler needs to "process Getguess first" is incorrect since "string guess = GetGuess();" is already processing/retrieving the return value.

Also, I think it's a good practice to initialize and declare all functions before int main() but then, it's up to how you organize all your code functions.

Comment: Hey there! Thank you so much for clarifying my doubts. Its been bugging me for quite awhile but your answer gave me a clearer pic. Honestly thanks a LOT